# Will omitting a return type in Kotlin cause issues?

Tags: kotlin

Consider the example below where I define two generic functions in the companion object of a generic data class:

```
data class CommonResponse<T>(
    var data: T? = null
) {
    companion object {
        // WITH return type
        fun <T> succeed1(): CommonResponse<T> = CommonResponse()
        // WITHOUT explicit return type
        fun <T> succeed2() = CommonResponse<T>()
    }
}
```

With the given context, both functions will have the same return signature. I have no doubt that they will both work correctly, but there is still a question confusing me:

- Will omitting the return type cause any issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to describe is the applicability of Type Inference for your function, `succeed2`. For [context](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/type-inference.html#type-inference):

> Kotlin has a concept of type inference for compile-time type information, meaning some type information in the code may be omitted, to be inferred by the compiler. There are two kinds of type inference supported by Kotlin.
>
> - Local type inference, for inferring types of expressions locally, in statement/expression scope;
> - Function signature type inference, for inferring types of function return values and/or parameters.

Type inference works in situations where the type context contains enough information for the type constraint solver to derive the expected type. So in the case of `succeed2` your function return value is giving enough [function signature type inference](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/type-inference.html#function-signature-type-inference), so it really doesn't matter much in this context.

**Argument Against Function Signature Type Inference**

If you're trying to control the signature of your function, then you can argue that explicitly declaring the return type will provide you with compile time errors. **Example**: Let's say we will unsafely (without the help of the IDE) refactor both functions to return `AnotherType<T>`

```
data class AnotherType<T>(
    val foo: T
)

data class CommonResponse<T>(
    var data: T? = null
) {
    companion object {
        // THIS WILL FAIL
        fun <T> succeed1(): CommonResponse<T> = AnotherType()
        // THIS WILL SUCCEED
        fun <T> succeed2() = AnotherType<T>()
    }

}
```

`succeed2` function signature type inference will be resolved to `AnotherType<T>`. (Whereas `succeed1` will fail to compile)

Answer (score -1):

This is called a [single-expression function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/functions.html#single-expression-functions).

In regular functions *(those with block body)*, we must declare the return type or it'll be `Unit`; however, in case of single-expression functions, the compiler infers the return type and generates the same output for both inferred and explicitly declared types.

So technically there's no difference **if** the inferred type is the type you actually want. *(you can also return an `ArrayList` and declare the type as `List`, which is another scenario)*

However, you might prefer explicitly declaring the return type for the sake of clarity.

---

**Official Kotlin Docs:**

> Single-expression functions﻿
> When a function returns a single expression, the curly braces can be omitted and the body is specified after a = symbol:
>
> ```kotlin
> fun double(x: Int): Int = x * 2
> ```
>
> Explicitly declaring the return type is optional when this can be inferred by the compiler:
>
> ```kotlin
> fun double(x: Int) = x * 2
> ```